# initiating a fortran exe

Tags: java

I would like to start out by saying that I am not a programmer and have had only the basics.  I am working on automating a model written in FORTRAN with some Java code.  I would like to use Java so I can potentially link my automation with some work performed by another group which was programmed in Java. I have been reading the postings on stackoverflow for some time, but haven't been able to get my program to work.  I have seen people mention using both:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

and

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder(cmd).start();
```

to run an executable file using Java (see code below).  When I run the Java program, I get no errors; however, the model hasn't run.  It runs fine when double clicking it in the folder, but not with Java.  I have also tried something simple, launching a web browser, which worked fine using either method. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks for the help.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String[] cmd={"C:\\TxtInOut\\rev591_64rel"};
   //     Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        Process p = new ProcessBuilder(cmd).start();
        p.waitFor();
      }
}
```

I am trying to automate the SWAT model which is primarily a hydrologic model.  I had tried using the file extension in the past (.exe), but it didn't make a difference.  I get the following when running the code suggested by Reimeus. (see my code below).

```
run:
forrtl: severe (24): end-of-file during read, unit 23, file C:\Users\Rachel\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Java21\file.cio

Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source             
rev591_64rel.exe   000007F7C1B28D7F  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
rev591_64rel.exe   000007F7C1B24663  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
rev591_64rel.exe   000007F7C1ABDF8F  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
rev591_64rel.exe   000007F7C1AA4E68  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
rev591_64rel.exe   000007F7C1AA3AA2  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
rev591_64rel.exe   000007F7C1A776BD  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
rev591_64rel.exe   000007F7C1949C26  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
rev591_64rel.exe   000007F7C18B1BF7  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
rev591_64rel.exe   000007F7C1B2C09C  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
rev591_64rel.exe   000007F7C1AEF4D2  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
rev591_64rel.exe   000007F7C1AEF3DE  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
KERNEL32.DLL       000007FFD58D1832  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
ntdll.dll          000007FFD81FD609  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

file.cio is the initial input file for the model I am trying to run.  There are many other input files that are called throughout the program too.  I currently have all the model input files in the same folder as the SWAT executable which works when manually starting the model.  Do I need to do something different when initiating in through Java?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        String[] cmd={"C:\\TxtInOut\\rev591_64rel.exe"};
   //     Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        Process p = new ProcessBuilder(cmd).start();
   //     p.waitFor();

    try (BufferedReader errorStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()))) {

    String line;
    while ((line = errorStream.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
}
```

Comment: What is the `rev591_64rel` file, exactly? Is it an executable or is it a data file of some kind? Does it have an extension that Windows is hiding from you?

Comment: Almost certainly a hidden Windows extension of `.exe` or perhaps `.lnk`. You have to use the entire filename, not the shortcut you can use in `cmd` or Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

`C:\\TxtInOut\\rev591_64rel` doesnt look like a Windows executable file (e.g. `.exe` or `.lnk`) - its missing the file extension. For both of these aforementioned extensions, 
add the extensions and check the `ErrorStream` to see what errors are being shown by the `Process` `p`:

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\TxtInOut\\rev591_64rel.lnk").start();

try (BufferedReader errorStream = 
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()))) {

    String line;
    while ((line = errorStream.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I checked the ErrorStream.  See above.

Comment: Does the command itself work ok when run on the command line? Does the command need to be run from a certain directory?

Comment: No.  It does not work properly when run from the command line.

Comment: Then it cant run correctly from Java either - best thing would be to check the documentation for `rev591_64rel` to ensure correct usage